# C# MVC3 - file array is null when posting

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am posting multiple files to my controller but it does not seem to find them. It says that `files` variable is `null`. I can't understand where is the problem.

HTML

```
<form action="/gallery/create" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
    <div class="file-holder">
        <div>
            <input type="file" name="files[]">
            <input type="file" name="files[]">
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Create">
</form>
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Gallery g, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
    string t = string.Empty;
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        t += file.FileName;
    }

    return Content(t);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `[]` from the name:

```
<input type="file" name="files">
<input type="file" name="files">
```

Comment: Did it work for your Qmal? I couldn't get this to work on a test. Pretty neat if it did though.

Comment: Yea it did, I never knew you can do it like that.

Comment: You might find the following bog post from the Haacked useful: http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx